# Decode messages with variabile length in Netty 4 MessageToMessageDecoder

Tags: java, netty

How to correctly decode multiple messages with variabile length in *Netty 4*? Currently my messages are being merged to one by decoder. Is there a way how to split them correctly?

I am using this *decode* method in **MessageToMessageDecoder**.

```
@Override
protected void decode(final ChannelHandlerContext paramChannelHandlerContext,
            final ByteBuf message, final List<Object> out) throws Exception {
    byte[] array = new byte[message.nioBuffer().remaining()];
    message.getBytes(0, array);
    out.add(new NettyMessage(array));
}
```

and this method for *encoding* messages to bytes in my **MessageToMessageEncoder**.

```
@Override
protected void encode(final ChannelHandlerContext ctx, final NettyMessage message,
        final List<Object> out) throws Exception {
    out.add(message.payload);
}
```

This is my **NettyMessage** class.

```
public class NettyMessage {
    public byte[] payload;

    public NettyMessage(final byte[] array) {
        this.payload = array;
    }
}
```

I am using Netty 4.0.23.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I had to implement **[MessageToByteEncoder](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/handler/codec/MessageToByteEncoder.html)**  and **[ByteToMessageDecoder](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/handler/codec/ByteToMessageDecoder.html)**. As encoder I used simple implementation with length of payload in header.

```
public class IntegerHeaderFrameEncoder extends MessageToByteEncoder<byte[]> {
    @Override
    protected void encode(final ChannelHandlerContext paramChannelHandlerContext,
            final byte[] msg, final ByteBuf out) throws Exception {
        out.writeInt(msg.length);
        out.writeBytes(msg);
    }
}
```

And as a decoder I used **[ReplayingDecoder](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/handler/codec/ReplayingDecoder.html)** to simplify implementation.

```
public class IntegerHeaderFrameDecoder extends ReplayingDecoder<Void> {
    @Override
    protected void decode(final ChannelHandlerContext ctx, final ByteBuf buf,
            final List<Object> out) throws Exception {
        out.add(buf.readBytes(buf.readInt()));
    }
}
```

Then added both to channel pipeline.

```
pipeline.addLast(new IntegerHeaderFrameDecoder());
pipeline.addLast(new IntegerHeaderFrameEncoder());
pipeline.addLast(new NettyMessageDecoder());
pipeline.addLast(new NettyMessageEncoder());
```

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you'll find [LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/handler/codec/LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder.html) useful. You can specify where the length indicator is located and how many bytes it is, along with a few other useful features like stripping the header.

```
public LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder(
        int maxFrameLength,
        int lengthFieldOffset, int lengthFieldLength,
        int lengthAdjustment, int initialBytesToStrip)
```

Extract from documentation:

```
A decoder that splits the received ByteBufs dynamically by the value of the length field in
the message. It is particularly useful when you decode a binary message which has an
integer header field that represents the length of the message body or the whole message.

The value of the length field in this example is 12 (0x0C) which represents the length of
"HELLO, WORLD". By default, the decoder assumes that the length field represents the 
number of the bytes that follows the length field. Therefore, it can be decoded with the
simplistic parameter combination.

 lengthFieldOffset   = 0
 lengthFieldLength   = 2
 lengthAdjustment    = 0
 initialBytesToStrip = 0 (= do not strip header)

 BEFORE DECODE (14 bytes)         AFTER DECODE (14 bytes)
 +--------+----------------+      +--------+----------------+
 | Length | Actual Content |----->| Length | Actual Content |
 | 0x000C | "HELLO, WORLD" |      | 0x000C | "HELLO, WORLD" |
 +--------+----------------+      +--------+----------------+
```